# Writing to console of parent process os.kill

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a program that includes a -p --pause flag with values 1 for pause and 2 for resume. The purpose of this is to allow a user to specifically pause the program (it's intended to run as a daemon) manually. Functionally, it works (it pauses and resumes when need be...the kill function also works, though is unrelated to this question now that I look at my code) but I can't get my messages to show up. Basically I would like the original parent program to let print to console when it is being paused or resumed from another place. I think this can be done with signals, but I'm not really sure how this is done, especially in Python (just learning it)
Thanks!

```
     if __Kill:
         os.system("kill %s" % old_pid)
         sys.exit()
     if int(__Pause) == 1:
         pause_proc(old_pid)
     elif int( __Pause) == 2:
         resume_proc(old_pid)

 def pause_proc(pid):
     print "Pausing Procedure"
     os.kill(pid, signal.SIGSTOP)

 def resume_proc(pid):
     os.kill(pid, signal.SIGCONT)
     print "Resuming Procedure"
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're process is running as a daemon, but you want it to print out to the stdout of the process you're (un)pausing?

Comment: Not quite...
1) Daemon starts running
2) From command line I pause daemon with ./daemon -p 1
3) Original Daemon (in different window) prints "Pausing"

Comment: Running a process as a daemon should disconnect the process from the terminal. If you want to do this, you need to not disconnect from the terminal, then the process is not a daemon.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29

Comment: Then I guess I have a terminology misunderstanding. I guess I don't want a daemon, just a process that runs in the background with no disconnect! Apologies for my ignorance! ha